# didReceiveRemoteNotification only works for a short time for background case then stops working

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am using push notifications for an iOS chat app.

I have successfully implemented and receive push notifications and also implemented background fetch.

When I upload a new build either for TestFlight or through he store, I can correctly run through the function didReceiveRemoteNotification until the completionHandler only for several push notifications.  ( about 10 or so ) in background mode.

After that the function does not run in background mode.  It either get's out of sync or stops working.  I know apple limits apps in background mode but not sure this is the case as this function call in my case only takes less than one second to process:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
    if state == .background {
        if saveNotificationData(userInfo: userInfo) {
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
        } else {
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)
        }
    } else {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)
    }
}

private func saveNotificationData(userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> Bool {

    let context = self.privateContext

    var result = false

    if let chatRoomId = (userInfo["chatRoomId"] as? String) {
        do {
            let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Room> = Room.fetchRequest()
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "chatRoomId == %@", chatRoomId)
            let fetchedResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            if fetchedResults.count > 0 {

                let message = Message(context: context)
                message.messageRoomId = userInfo["chatRoomId"] as? String
                message.messageCreatorUserId = userInfo["user_id"] as? String
                message.messageText = userInfo["message_text"] as? String
                message.messageChatRoom = fetchedResults.first!

                do {
                    try context.save()
                    result = true
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        } catch {

            // error fetching list
            print("Could not fetch \(error)")
        }
    }

    return result

}
```

I have tried so many different ways to do this including using the main context instead of a defined background context.  Putting the save function in a context.perform block, dispatching to main queue prior to returning the completionHandler.

But the result is always the same.  The functions run as expected for the first few notifications and then stop working in background mode.  Either getting out of sync or just being locked out.  It seems the previous function execution continues when the next push is received which throws things out of order.

I am also implementing didReceive and willPresent but I have removed them completely to see if it made any difference but it did not.  Really stuck here and no idea what is causing the problem.

I wonder if it is an out of sync case if when executing the new push I can cancel what is ongoing from the previous one?  But that may not be the problem.

Comment: How frequently do you send them? I _suppose_ Apple would reasonably throttle them —regardless of how long it takes...and if it’s happening every time after 10 we’ll then I’d say is what Apple throttles. Just not sure when again it allows delivery

Comment: it's not always after ten but after several sent in shot succession.  But that's the way all chat apps work and I don't see the same thing happening in other chat apps.  Particularly with chat room apps sending many push notifications in short sequence.  And the problem is if it is being throttled, how do I know when that will be reset if at all?

Comment: what I want is some control over the process so if it is being throttled I want to know what the criteria is so I can add appropriate logic to my app to ignore notifications if that threshold is about to be achieved so as not to lock it out completely for an indeterminate period of time